# How do I find where a django template variable comes from in the python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Is there a good general way of finding the line of python code responsible for passing in variables to django templates?  When newly picking up a large code base, and I see `{{ x.y }}` in the template, and nothing obviously related (by how things are named) to `x` in the `{% load ... %}`, what do I do? Where can I find this variable in the python so that I can change it or related code?

My current solutions tend to be tedious and overwhelming. It's a lot of searching, but I would like to be able to just know where to look.

Comment: A good starting point would be figuring out the view that would render that template. The next place I would look is any middlewares, or template context processors injecting the variable.

Comment: django-debug-toolbar will let you see the context each context processor is providing

Comment: Start with the URL pattern and work backwards to the view that matches the pattern. If you still can't find what you're looking for, see if there are any context processors or template tags that have been added that are adding the variable(s) to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the URL of the page. Then go to urls.py and look at which view is linked to the URL. Then open views.py and search for the view which the URL linked to.

In that view, the variable 'x' should be there. If it's not, then check the template context processors and middlewares as karthikr suggested.

Comment: Worked. Found the 'x' in the correct view, and followed that to a models file where 'y' was made. Thanks!